# How to generate and link to an arbitrary file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's what I'm trying to do. Let's say the user is looking at the `foo` view for the `foo` action of the `bar` controller, and I've got a variable called `@userName`.

bar_controller.rb

```
class BarController
  def foo
    @userName = getUserName();
  end
```

foo.html.erb

```
Hi mom!
```

I want to create a filed called `<%= @userName %>.myExt` with the information `Hi, I'm <%= @userName %>!` in it and put a link to it in the view. How do I do this?

i.e. final:

bar_controller.rb

```
def foo
  @userName = getUserName();
  create_myExt_file(@userName);
```

foo.html.erb

```
Hi mom! Click <%= generate link to @userName.myExt, "here" %> to view!
```

<@userName>.myExt

```
Hi, I'm <@userName>!
```

Ideally the @userName.myExt file doesn't have to actually be written to the hard drive, but could be created from a template or something. I don't know how to do this!

Thanks!

Comment: why do that ? it's complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, generate the file as a string, such as:

```
s = get_file_contents
```

Then, in your controller, send it to the client, along with a suggested filename:

```
send_data s, :filename => 'example.text'
```

Finally, to use an ERB template, you can just [`render_to_string`](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000465).